# Customized ActionBar yields different layout views

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am creating an application with customized actionbar. However with different screen resolutions, I got different views. I am trying to fix it but had no ways to implement the solution.

This is the layout from an emulator with 480 x 800 resolution (HDPI):

[image]

On the other hand, this is the output from an emulator with 720 x 1280 (XHDPI) with same codes:

[image]

As you can see, the icon with settings is displayed on the upper right corner. Is this default? What are the possible means to remove this and display the correct and expected layout I got from HDPI layout?

By the way, here's the XML code for the customized ActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_line_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#8284A3" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_line_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_line_1" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#6E7095" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_line_2"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_solid_iformula"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_top_left_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_nav_button"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/iformula_top_btn_add"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_top_right_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_nav_button"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/iformula_top_btn_edit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_top_navigation_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/main_top_right_button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_top_right_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/below_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_action_bar" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#00103D" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, how to remove the icon with Settings? I need the same output with HDPI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem. It turns out I added a menu which was technically useless in my application found on the main. Snippet here:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    .....
    return true;
}
```

Simply delete this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the resolution but the type of device you're picking. The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

Comment: Interesting information. So this means that for devices with hardware keys, I will get the same layout? Also, for those without menu keys, this will ALWAYS show?

Comment: Yes. It will ALWAYS show there for devices without hardware keys as long as you have a menu.

Comment: What do you mean with the Menu? Does this mean I created the "Settings" menu explicitly?

Comment: Yes. As long as there are menu options it will show the overflow icon. It's the same as pressing the settings hardware button on a phone which has one, like the S3 etc..